# Average run time of an if statement

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

I have an algorithm that looks something like this:

```
if condition 
    O(1) algorithm 
else
    O(n)
```

Now the worst case runtime is O(n) when the condition is always false. However, in practice, the condition is usually true. How do I analyze the average runtime complexity of this algorithm? Or is it not even applicable? Is amortized analysis more appropriate?

Comment: Does `condition` depend on `n`?  If so, perhaps it can be captured in the `f(n)` used to describe the overall Big-O.

Comment: Asymptotic Analysis is used to define the bounds w.r.t time under which a procedure can run. So, your piece of code has lower bound `Ω(1)` i.e atleast constant complexity. Upper bound `O(n)`. And as you said `the condition is usually true`, so on an average `constant complexity i.e O(1)`. Note, a procedure's complexity is described by `lower, upper and average`.

Comment: @sameerkn I just realized Big O notation **is** asymptotic analysis. I actually meant amortized analysis.

Comment: It's a bit similar to quicksort time complexity. On average, it's O(nlogn), but in worst case, it's O(n^2).

Comment: @PaulProgrammer The condition depends on the nature of the input data but not directly on n.

Comment: @shole That is why I am asking about worst-case vs average vs amortized analysis. Big-O can describe each of these.

Answer (score 3):

The algorithm is asymptotically **`O(n)`** since with growing `n` the complexity is growing too, linearly. However, coefficient will be pretty low according to the probability of `O(n)` case.

It cannot be `O(1)` because it would mean that changing `n` does not affect expected algorithm *time* - and it's not true.

**Update:** What if the O(n) case only occurs some very small percentage of the time?

If `false` value is **expected**, even very rarely, then I would still say that its `O(n)`.
If it is some sort of **unexpected, exceptional case**, then probably it can be called `O(1)`.

For example, if 0.0001% of values are `false`, then its `O(n)`, because increasing `n` will still increase algorithm time.
If it is always `true` **unless** there is a problem / special "bad" input case / exceptions / errors, and in good case you will never get `false`, then its `O(1)`.
That's how I see it, I may be wrong :)

Comment: What if the O(n) case only occurs some very small percentage of the time?

Answer (score 1):

Big-O analysis is used to describe the worst-case complexity, so the overall big-O of this algorithm is O(n).

Your if-condition is simply an optimization -- you could simply state that in your analysis that you expect the optimization to be effective *x%* of the time...

Comment: I would not agree that Big-O analysis is used to describe the worst-case complexity. QuickSort is `O(n^2)` in its worst case, but it is asymptotically `O(N*logN)`.

Comment: From what I remember from my analysis of algorithms class, big-O notation is used for average and asymptotic analysis as well as worst case.

Comment: I just realized Big O notation **is** asymptotic analysis. I had that confused with amortized analysis.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think "averge complexity is O(n)" is a correct statment, since average complexity should not be worst than worst case complexity.

And if you want to find a better number, you will need to define what average means from definition of average case complexity. It is usually related to distribution of input. Once you find out the probability that the condition is false "on average", you can find out the complexity.
I suggest you to take a look at this example.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis#Dynamic_Array

It is also helpful if you tell us more about the condition/algorithm.

In fact, I think maybe what you want is not theoretical complexity. I guess you want a benchmark/time profiling with real life data.

Answer (score 0):

let x = number of times that the condition is false.

if x can be bounded by a constant number, then the algorithm is O(1). Otherwise it is O(n).